# How to find out which type of Pcie express lanes allotted in my free M.2 slot

Tags: ssd, nvme

I have Acer Aspire 5 A515-51g with Nvidia Geforce 940mx and i opened my laptop and there i found a M.2 Nvme slot of M-type but i don't know does it support 3.0x4 express lane or 3.0x2, because for upgrading to Nvme ssd it should be 3.0x4 for best speed. How to find this?

Answer (score 0):

"lspci" can help you gatherinformation about PCI buses in your system and devices connected to them.

```
 sudo lspci -vv
```

we use -vv to be more verbose and display more details.  This  level  includes
everything deemed useful.

Then look under Non-Volatile memory controller